# Trouble with converting fixed-amount of for loops to parametrized amount

Tags: java, loops, methods, refactoring

I am trying to make a generator for Spirals being parametrized by the amount of dimensions the answer should have.

**Example on 2 dimensions (x, y)**

```
static void caller()
{
  for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
  for (int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
  {
     int y = (t-x);
     printAllPossibleSigns(0, x, y);
  }
}
```

**Example on 3 dimensions (x, y, z)**

```
static void caller()
{
  for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
  for (int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y <= (t-x); y++)
  {
     int z = (t-x-y);
     printAllPossibleSigns(0, x, y, z);
  }
}
```

**Example on 4 dimensions (x, y, z, alpha)**

```
static void caller()
{
  for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
  for (int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y <= (t-x); y++)
  for (int z = 0; z <= (t-x-y); z++)
  {
     int alpha = (t-x-y-z);
     printAllPossibleSigns(0, x, y, z, alpha);
  }
}
```

However now I am trying to generate only 1 result (or batch of results) at once:

So how exactly would I need to do it now if I want to use it for an iterator, so using the `next()` it should retrieve 'the result' of one `printAllPossibleSigns(0, ...);` call.

It would be enough already if there would be some method replacing the bunch of `for-loops` in which I give as input the `t` and an array holding the `x`-value in case of `x, y`; holding the `x, y`-value in case of `x, y, z`; the `x, y, z`-value in case of `x, y, z, alpha`, etc.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: I would use a callback to be called for each "result".  Having it return and find where it was each time would be very expensive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Still would need to find a way to construct the `for-loops` though.

Comment: You have constructed them already.  Trying to turn these into one method is likely to be more complicated and slower. Java 8 will have a more elegant way of doing it with method currying, but don't expect it to be fast ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have just constructed them for examples of 2, 3 or 4 dimensions. I want to have this structure on a paremeter `dimension` responsible for the amount of dimensions and thus the amount of loops. But thinking about it is kind of cracking my brain.

Comment: Which also means it is unlikely to work or if it does work it will be horribly confusing.  BTW: If it is complicated for you imagine the poor, dumb JIT optimiser, it can't do as good job unless the code is simple to follow.  In short, I could give you an answer but I suspect it will have much more code and be much harder to understand and much slower as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well I need to use it for 7 dimensions. I'm aware of the possible cost to compute it but I actually don't need to compute that many combinations. So was just thinking that a parametrized one might have been nicer, but atleast 7 dimensions (in the sense of 7 for-loops) is easy to understand.

Comment: I suggest you read up on using MethodHandles in Java 7 and currying and nicer doesn't come to mind. ;)  What you could do is have a 7 dimension loop where the inner loops are done once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, instead of stalling there is a solution which will work for ints, a general solution is much harder, note: This will "spiral" out in boxes.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    caller(10, 7, new Callback<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public void on(int[] ints) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
        }
    });
}

interface Callback<T> {
    public void on(T t);
}

public static void caller(int maxSum, int dimensions, Callback<int[]> callback) {
    int[] ints = new int[dimensions];
    for (int t = 0; t < maxSum; t++) {
        caller(t, 0, ints, callback);
    }
}

private static void caller(int sum, int idx, int[] ints, Callback<int[]> callback) {
    if (idx == ints.length) {
        callback.on(ints);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
        ints[idx] = i;
        caller(sum - i, idx+1, ints, callback);
    }
}
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]

...

[7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[7, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[7, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```