# Java issues with notify() / wait()

Tags: java, wait, notify

I have a generator inside an `Iterator` instance, which generates and returns one item every time `next()` is called on the iterator. It does seem to kind of work, but I am getting `null` values returned.

Class code:

```
package spiral;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class Spiral7DGenerator implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {
    private boolean releaseNext = false;
    private List<Integer> releaseList;

    public Spiral7DGenerator() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int t = 0; true; t++) {
                    loops(t);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> next() {
        synchronized(this) {
            releaseNext = true;
            notify();
            return releaseList;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    private void loops(int t) {
        for (int d1 = 0; d1 <= t; d1++) {
            for (int d2 = 0; d2 <= (t - d1); d2++) {
                for (int d3 = 0; d3 <= (t - d1 - d2); d3++) {
                    for (int d4 = 0; d4 <= (t - d1 - d2 - d3); d4++) {
                        for (int d5 = 0; d5 <= (t - d1 - d2 - d3 - d4); d5++) {
                            for (int d6 = 0; d6 <= (t - d1 - d2 - d3 - d4 - d5); d6++) {
                                int d7 = (t - d1 - d2 - d3 - d4 - d5 - d6);
                                generate(0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void generate(int pos, Integer... array) {
        if (pos == array.length) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
            synchronized(this) {
                while (!releaseNext) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Spiral7DGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            releaseNext = false;
            releaseList = list;
            return;
        }
        generate(pos + 1, array);
        array[pos] = -array[pos];
        if (array[pos] != 0) {
            generate(pos + 1, array);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing code:

```
package spiral;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Beheerder
 */
public class Spiral7DGeneratorTest {

    public Spiral7DGeneratorTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testHasNext() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testNext() {
        System.out.println("test");
        Spiral7DGenerator s7dg = new Spiral7DGenerator();
        System.out.println("s7dg.next() = " + s7dg.next());
        System.out.println("s7dg.next() = " + s7dg.next());
        System.out.println("s7dg.next() = " + s7dg.next());
        System.out.println("s7dg.next() = " + s7dg.next());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
    }

}
```

Test output:

```
test
s7dg.next() = null
s7dg.next() = null
s7dg.next() = null
s7dg.next() = null
```

I'm afraid it is just a simple thing, but I am overlooking it completely.

Comment: Do you really need to write such a complex code. It is quite unreadable and hard to understand for me atleaset. I am running out of memory while reading those nested for loops.

Comment: @JunedAhsan While the question itself is not about that code, I can explain why it is such complex. That is because making spirals in general is complex, of course I would love to make it generic instead of this, but that is currently simply too hard for me.

Comment: Your loop in Spiral7DGenerator() const is never ending and is starting new thread on each iteration..Its a mistake (as memory is limited)

Comment: Using multiple threads is rarely a way to make your code simpler. I still think this is much simpler and more likely to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074982/trouble-with-converting-fixed-amount-of-for-loops-to-parametrized-amount

Comment: Another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570132/generator-functions-equivalent-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that the worker thread feeds a stream of results to the main thread, correct?

I suggest that you do not attempt to construct the concurrency control logic by hand, but instead use a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html). The code would look like:

```
public class Spiral7DGenerator implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {
    private BlockingQueue<List<Integer>> spirals = new SynchronousQueue<List<Integer>>();

    @Override
    public List<Integer> next() {
        return spirals.take();
    }

    private void generate(int pos, Integer... array) {
        if (pos == array.length) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
            spirals.put(list);
            return;
        }
    // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need. It is such a shame though that Java has no Python's `yield` equivalent.

Comment: It certainly is. Scala, of course, has added continuations which let you build things like generators. I think that's unlikely to ever come to Java, though.

Comment: Actually, this might not be 100% what I want. I want `generate()` to only do something when `spirals.isEmpty()`. Can the `BlockingQueue` be (easily) modified such that it blocks when `spirals.size() > threshold`? As I would like it to block/wait whenever `spirals.size() > 0`. Then wait until `next()` has been called, and then generate the next element again, etc.

Comment: As it is, `spirals.put` will block until the main thread comes along and calls `spirals.take`, so there will only ever be one value passing through the queue at a time. If you want to have some larger but still fixed limit on the size of the queue, replace the `SynchronousQueue` with an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) of whatever capacity you need.

Comment: Ah ok so `SynchronousQueue` is indeed exactly what I need, I should have read the documentation before asking.

Comment: The JDK documentation is generally very good, and the stuff for the concurrency classes is excellent. I would agree that it's worth a read :).

Answer (score 5):

I haven't fully understood your code but two points I can make:

- `releaseList` must be declared `volatile` (at least) as it is being assigned outside a synchronized block.
- your `next` method does not wait for the notified thread to wake up and produce a result. This is a race condition. You need `next` to wait on an extra mutex (or something) to allow the generator to notify that `releaseList` has been set. (Actually, when you do this, you won't need to make `releaseList` volatile any more.)

Comment: I suspect it's the fact that `next()` does not wait for the worker thread at all that's leading to all the nulls. You're absolutely right about `releaseList` (and `releaseNext`) not being safely updated, too.